# Knockout.js nested foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a list of key value pairs (KVP) and I want to list 2 KVPs in every table row. From my limited Knockout knowledge, I figured that if I have an array of arrays, then I can use a nested `foreach` to achieve this.

**jsfiddle code** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UmzWe/).

But this is not outputting table cells as expected. What is wrong?

**edit: updated fiddle link**

Comment: `But this is not outputting table cells as expected`, can you please explain the issue clearly, how can we generate the issue on your given fiddle ?

Comment: @gaurav, you can just click on run to see the output. i was expecting a 2x2 table, but got nothing. when i inspect the html using chrome, i see only <tr> generated, but no <td>...pls let me know if i can clarify further.

Comment: sorry just discovered that the fiddle link was wrong. i updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:
`KVPairs: ko.observableArray(filter.KVPairs)`

Comment: That's `line 23` of the fiddle, by the way. You're referencing the outer passed in list of filters, rather than the inner variable filter.

Comment: Thanks!! shame on me for the mistake :(

Answer (score 2):

It's seems I didn't understand your question. However, I'll leave this up in case you were curious how to display the phone numbers.

---

Your foreach should go on the tbody tag: http://jsfiddle.net/Vcwv6/4/

Also, I add a virtual element.

```
<!-- ko foreach: phones -->
<td>
    <select data-bind="value: type, options: $root.types"></select>
    <input data-bind='value: number' />
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
```